# Consume webservices in Blackberry

Tags: xml, json, web-services, blackberry, ksoap2

We are trying to consume webservices in blackberry.We are very new in developing apps on blackberry.After searching web we found that we can use org.json.me jar to consume json webservices in blackberry,But it didn't worked then we found that we can consume xml based webservices in BB.But we don't know how to get and send data to the webservice.

The webservice url we got giving xml response is :

http://somedomainname.com/wcfservice/RestServiceImpl.svc/XML/log

Please guide or suggest a way to consume json / xml /ksoap web service in BB.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: this link doesn't return XML !

Comment: i didn't have posted the actual url

Comment: Great ! I think you should read more in BB documentation and Knowledge Base, they provide lot of working samples that I tested and they are running well, check the examples provided below in my answer from their knowledge base ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to retrieve and parse json in BB:

```
import net.rim.device.api.io.URI;
import net.rim.device.api.io.messaging.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.json.me.*;

public class NetworkSample extends UiApplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        NetworkSample app = new NetworkSample();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    public NetworkSample() 
    {
        pushScreen(new ParseJSONSample());
    }
}

class ParseJSONSample extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{

    ButtonField _btnJSON = new ButtonField(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

    private static UiApplication _app = UiApplication.getUiApplication();

    public ParseJSONSample()
    {
        _btnJSON.setChangeListener(this);
        _btnJSON.setLabel("Fetch page");

        add(_btnJSON);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field button, int unused)
    {

        if(button == _btnJSON)
        {

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Message response = null;
                    String uriStr = "http://docs.blackberry.com/sampledata.json"; 
                    BlockingSenderDestination bsd = null;
                    try
                    {
                        bsd = (BlockingSenderDestination)
                                    DestinationFactory.getSenderDestination
                                        ("CommAPISample", URI.create(uriStr));
                        if(bsd == null)
                        {
                            bsd =
                              DestinationFactory.createBlockingSenderDestination
                                  (new Context("CommAPISample"),
                                   URI.create(uriStr), new JSONMessageProcessor()
                                   );
                        }

                        // Send message and wait for response
                        response = bsd.sendReceive();
                        _json = response.getObjectPayload();

                        if(_json != null)
                        {
                            _app.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                            {

                                public void run() 
                                {
                                    _app.pushScreen(new JSONOutputScreen(_json));
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.toString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if(bsd != null)
                        {
                            bsd.release();
                        }
                    }
                }


            });
            t.start();

        }

}

class JSONOutputScreen extends MainScreen implements TreeFieldCallback 
{

    private TreeField _treeField;

    public JSONOutputScreen(Object JSONData)
    {
        _treeField = new TreeField(this, Field.FOCUSABLE);
        add(_treeField);
        setTree(JSONData);
    }

    void setTree(Object obj)
    {
        int parentNode = 0;

        _treeField.deleteAll();

        try
        {
            if(obj instanceof JSONArray)
            {
                parentNode = populateTreeArray
                                  (_treeField, (JSONArray) obj, parentNode);
            }
            else if(obj instanceof JSONObject)
            {
                parentNode = populateTreeObject
                                 (_treeField, (JSONObject) obj, parentNode);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        _treeField.setCurrentNode(parentNode);
    }


    // Populate the trees with JSON arrays
    int populateTreeArray(TreeField tree, JSONArray o, int p) throws JSONException
    {
        Object temp;
        int newParent;

        newParent = tree.addChildNode(p, "Array " + p);

        for(int i = 0; i < o.length(); ++i)
        {
            temp = o.get(i);

            if(temp == null || temp.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(temp instanceof JSONArray)
            {
                 // Array of arrays
                populateTreeArray(tree, (JSONArray) temp, newParent);
            }
            else if(temp instanceof JSONObject)
            {
                // Array of objects
                populateTreeObject(tree, (JSONObject) temp, newParent);
            }
            else
            { // other values
                newParent = tree.addSiblingNode(newParent, temp.toString());
            }
        }

        return newParent;
    }


    // Populate the tree with JSON objects
    int populateTreeObject(TreeField tree, JSONObject o, int p) throws JSONException
    {
        Object temp;

        int newParent = tree.addChildNode(p, "Object" + p);

        JSONArray a = o.names();

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i)
        {
            temp = o.get(a.getString(i));

            if(temp == null || temp.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(temp instanceof JSONArray)
            {
                populateTreeArray(tree, (JSONArray) temp, newParent);
            }
            else if(temp instanceof JSONObject)
            {
                populateTreeObject(tree, (JSONObject) temp, newParent);
            }
            else
            {
                tree.addSiblingNode
                        (newParent, a.getString(i) + ": " + temp.toString());
            }
        }

        return newParent;
    }


    public void drawTreeItem(TreeField treeField, Graphics graphics, int node,
            int y, int width, int indent) 
    {
        if(treeField == _treeField)
        {
            Object cookie = _treeField.getCookie(node);
            if(cookie instanceof String)
            {
                String text = (String) cookie;
                graphics.drawText(text, indent, y, Graphics.ELLIPSIS, width);
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean onSavePrompt()
    {
        // Suppress the save dialog
        return true;
    }

}
```

Source: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Code_sample_Parse_JSON_data_structure_1319797_11.jsp

And about how to retrieve and parse XML in BB:

```
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

class XML_Parsing_Sample extends UiApplication{
    //creating a member variable for the MainScreen
    MainScreen _screen= new MainScreen();
    //string variables to store the values of the XML document
    String _node,_element;
    Connection _connectionthread;

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        XML_Parsing_Sample application = new XML_Parsing_Sample();
        //create a new instance of the application
        //and start the application on the event thread
        application.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public XML_Parsing_Sample() {
        _screen.setTitle("XML Parsing");//setting title
        _screen.add(new RichTextField("Requesting....."));
        _screen.add(new SeparatorField());
        pushScreen(_screen); // creating a screen
        //creating a connection thread to run in the background
        _connectionthread = new Connection();
        _connectionthread.start();//starting the thread operation
    }

    public void updateField(String node, String element){
        //receiving the parsed node and its value from the thread
        //and updating it here
        //so it can be displayed on the screen
        String title="Title";
        _screen.add(new RichTextField(node+" : "+element));

        if(node.equals(title)){
            _screen.add(new SeparatorField());
        }
    }

    private class Connection extends Thread{
        public Connection(){
            super();
        }

        public void run(){
            // define variables later used for parsing
            Document doc;
            StreamConnection conn;

            try{
                //providing the location of the XML file,
                //your address might be different
                conn=(StreamConnection)Connector.open
                  ("http://localhost:8000/content/test.xml");
                //next few lines creates variables to open a
                //stream, parse it, collect XML data and
                //extract the data which is required.
                //In this case they are elements,
                //node and the values of an element
                DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory
                  = DocumentBuilderFactory. newInstance(); 
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder
                  = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                docBuilder.isValidating();
                doc = docBuilder.parse(conn.openInputStream());
                doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
                NodeList list=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
                _node=new String();
                _element = new String();
                //this "for" loop is used to parse through the
                //XML document and extract all elements and their
                //value, so they can be displayed on the device

                for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){
                    Node value=list.item(i).
                      getChildNodes().item(0);
                    _node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
                    _element=value.getNodeValue();
                    updateField(_node,_element);
                }//end for
            }//end try
            //will catch any exception thrown by the XML parser
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }//end connection function
    }// end connection class
}//end XML_Parsing_Sample
```

Source: http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800599/How_To_-_Use_the_XML_Parser.html?nodeid=820554&vernum=0

Comment: thanks for replying but i am unable to import `org.json.me.*;` in my blackberry project

Comment: Download and add the package to your project from this link: https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/